# I Gave My Site Access to My Gmail's Google Contacts... Now What?

Tags: php, api, contacts

I'm trying to use the Google Contacts API to pull a list of contacts from Gmail.  I figured out how to give my site access to my Gmail account's contacts.  I'm not sure what the next step is.

What do I do next to allow my site to download a list of contacts?

Thanks in advance,

John

**EDIT**: Not sure if it's relevant to my question, but I am using PHP.  I've read up on how Google Contacts API delivers its results in XML format, but I'm not sure how to pull it using PHP.

Comment: Start Here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpgooglecontact/index.html

Comment: @RobertPitt, thanks, I've been studying that for a while.  When I try the code provided in that tutorial, it returns a blank page, even when I append the access token to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

To get a complete list of all contacts, do the following GET

```
GET https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/myname%40gmail.com/full
```

(replacing `myname%40gmail.com` with the relevant gmail address.)

See [here for more details](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_without_query)